# How to upload file by content uri in WebView

Tags: android, file-upload, android-webview

## Typical Scenario

In order to upload a file using `WebView`, it's typically needed to override `WebChromeClient`, and start a file chooser `Activity` for result:

```
    ...
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                                         FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FilePickerActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            return true;
        }
    });
    ...
```

Then, once file is selected (for simplicity, only a single file can be selected at a time), `onActivityResult()` is called with a file uri stored in a `data` object. So, the uri is retrieved and handed over to `filePathCallback` and the file gets uploaded:

```
...
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(new Uri[] {data.getData()});
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
...
```

Basically, `filePathCallback` requires a **uri** to a file so that to upload it.

## The problem

What if I have only an `InputStream` that contains the data I need to upload rather than a file with a URI? And I cannot save that data to a file so that to generate a URI (for security reasons). Is there a way to upload the data as a file in such case? In particular, can I convert an `InputStream` to a content URI and then upload it?

### Approach 1

This approach works fine, if **uri** is generated using `Uri.fromFile()` as below:

```
...
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
...
```

### Approach 2

If I implement my own `ContentProvider` and override `openFile` there in such a way, that it uses `ParcelFileDescriptor.open()` to create a `ParcelFileDescriptor`, then uploading a file based on a uri provided by `getContentUri(...)` is working without problems:

#### FileUploadProvider.java

```
public class FileUploadProvider extends ContentProvider {

    public static Uri getContentUri(String name) {
        return new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme("content")
            .authority(PROVIDER_AUTHORITY)
            .appendEncodedPath(name)
            .appendQueryParameter(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            .build();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<String> segments = uri.getPathSegments();
        File file = new File(getContext().getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(),
                TextUtils.join(File.separator, segments));
    
        return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
    }
    ...
}
```

### Approach 3

However, if I create a `ParcelFileDescriptor` with help of `ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe()`, then file upload never finishes, so it basically doesn't work:

```
...
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<String> segments = uri.getPathSegments();
    File file = new File(getContext().getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(),
            TextUtils.join(File.separator, segments));

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    ParcelFileDescriptor[] pipe;
    try {
        pipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    ParcelFileDescriptor readPart = pipe[0];
    ParcelFileDescriptor writePart = pipe[1];
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream(writePart));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return readPart;
}
...
```

### Approach 4

To make matters worse, if I create a `ParcelFileDescriptor` with help of `MemoryFile`, then file upload never finishes as well:

```
...
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<String> segments = uri.getPathSegments();
    File file = new File(getContext().getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(),
            TextUtils.join(File.separator, segments));

    try {
        MemoryFile memoryFile = new MemoryFile(file.getName(), (int) file.length());
        byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        memoryFile.writeBytes(fileBytes, 0, 0, (int) file.length());
        Method method = memoryFile.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getFileDescriptor");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = (FileDescriptor) method.invoke(memoryFile);
        Constructor<ParcelFileDescriptor> constructor = ParcelFileDescriptor.class.getConstructor(FileDescriptor.class);
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = constructor.newInstance(fileDescriptor);
        return parcelFileDescriptor;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
...
```

Why is file upload not working for **Approach 3** and **Approach 4**?

## Example

I created a sample app to showcase my issue [here](https://github.com/Tester2012/WebViewUpload).

Below are steps to follow to reproduce it. First log in to your gmail account and click "create new message".

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

My colleagues have found a solution to this with help of `StorageManager` - please read more about the component [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager).

First, create a callback that handles file system requests from `ProxyFileDescriptor` in `FileUploadProvider`:

```
private static class CustomProxyFileDescriptorCallback extends ProxyFileDescriptorCallback {
    private ByteArrayInputStream inputStream;
    private long length;

    public CustomProxyFileDescriptorCallback(File file) {
        try {
            byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
            length = fileBytes.length;
            inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // do nothing here
        }

    }

    @Override
    public long onGetSize() {
        return length;
    }

    @Override
    public int onRead(long offset, int size, byte[] out) {
        inputStream.skip(offset);
        return inputStream.read(out,0, size);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease() {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //ignore this for now
        }
        inputStream = null;
    }
}
```

Then, create a file descriptor using `StorageManager` that will read the `InputStream` with help of the callback above.

```
...
        StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
        ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor;
        try {
            descriptor = storageManager.openProxyFileDescriptor(
                    ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY,
                    new CustomProxyFileDescriptorCallback(file),
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return descriptor;
...
```

Please find the full code on github [here](https://github.com/Tester2012/WebViewUpload).

## Limitation

This approach is working only for Android API higher than `25`.